# Copy field into column before Replace Into

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which stores user-published articles. The owner can modify their article at any time.

I do want to add a backup feature, in case the user accidentally deletes the content of their article or something else goes wrong when they update it.

For this reason, I have the `content` column which stores the content of the article, as well as a `backup_content` which is intended to keep a copy of the content before the last update.

The user has a "Restore" button which is meant to replace the new content with the backup. Very much like an "Undo" feature.

My prepared statement to insert/update an article is as follows:

```
REPLACE INTO custom_pages (name, banner_url, full_url, backup_content, content, updated_on) VALUES (?, ?, ?, content, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Here, I tried putting the previous value of `content` in `backup_content` and then changing `content` with the new value. Doing so sets the `backup_content` to `NULL` however.

I've seen a few answers on SO on how to achieve a copy, but those answers seem to apply strictly for `update` and `insert`, and don't seem to work in `Replace` queries. I'd prefer one statement over two, and that's where I'm having trouble.

Is there any way to achieve such copy in a single Replace statement?

[image: Table Image]

Comment: Which column is unique? `name`, I presume. This should be achievable with `INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`  What you're seeing with `REPLACE` is exactly as described here. https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/01/18/insert-on-duplicate-key-update-and-replace-into/  Post `SHOW CREATE TABLE custom_pages`, if you don't mind.

Comment: Check if this is what you want http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6b0672/1/0 I've assumed that name is PK but you should change it to fit your schema

Comment: @lad2025, I see an Insert and a Replace query. I'd prefer just 1 query if possible(?) and as such I cannot use `where name = xxx`. The Replace query works great if I am updating an existing field, but when creating a new it doesn't work.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski both `name` and `full_url` are unique keys.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski added image

Comment: @Chris Where is the problem with insert? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f4a0d/1/0

Comment: @lad2025, there is none. Just wondering if it can be done with 1 query rather than 2.

Comment: @Chris REPLACE...SELECT is technically one query. But I'm also finishing up an `INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY` answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also place my support behind [Gordon Linoff's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34120140/541091) that you create a continuous update history via triggers and one-to-many related tables.

However, if a significant architectural change is not practical for you right now, you can achieve what you are attempting [with `INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) instead of the older `REPLACE INTO` feature.

Using `REPLACE INTO...SELECT FROM` may result in more than one access against the table's index, but `INSERT INTO...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` should hit it only once.

Since `name` has a unique index, the presumption is that you never attempt  to `UPDATE`, and instead always execute an `INSERT` which copies the old value to `backup_content`.

```
-- Inserting a row which does not yet exist..
INSERT INTO custom_pages (name, banner_url, full_url, content)
  VALUES ('uniquename', 'http://example.com', 'http://example.com', 'this is the original content');



-- In practice, you use this format:
-- uniquename already exists, so update necessary fields
INSERT INTO custom_pages (name, banner_url, full_url, content) 
  VALUES ('uniquename', 'http://example.com', 'http://example.com', 'this is new content')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    -- Update from the VALUES() list
    banner_url = VALUES(banner_url),
    -- Set backup_content to old content BEFORE updating
    -- content from VALUES()
    backup_content = content,
    content = VALUES(content),
    updated_on = NOW();
```

Using this method, you would never use the first `INSERT` statement without its `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause. Instead, always use the second one; rows that don't exist by unique key will be created, those that already exist will be updated.

Here it is in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f687/1

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should re-think your data structure. If you want to preserve history, then use a separate table not column. Something like `custom_pages_history`. You would remove the `backup_content` column from your table and instead rely on the history table.

Then, define a trigger on inserts and updates to *insert* a row into the history table.

The advantages of this approach are:

- You have complete history of all the articles.
- The changes will be timestamped.
- A user can go back to any earlier version of the article, if desired.

This doesn't directly answer your question about replace. Instead of `replace` you would do an update from the history table.